# finding complex $n$-th root

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$z^8=5$$

So I have $$z=\sqrt[8]{5}\operatorname*{cis}\left(\frac{0+2\pi k}{8}\right)\text{, k=0,1,...,4}$$

But for $k=1$, I get $\sqrt[8]{5}\operatorname*{cis}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and taking $(\sqrt[8]{5}\operatorname*{cis}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right))^8\neq5$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is $cis$ here?

Comment: @A.G. I guess it is c for cos, i for $i$ and $s$ for sin

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28cis%28pi%2F4%29%29%5E8&x=0&y=0.

Comment: @haqnatural Yeah, it makes sense, but then it is no problem since $(cis\frac{\pi}{4})^8=cis2\pi=1$ and everything is alright.

Comment: "$(\sqrt[8]{5}cis\frac{\pi}{4})^8\neq5$" Why not?  I'm not sure what response you want other than "yes, it is"... because ... it does.  Why do you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong here $$(\sqrt[8]{5}cis\frac{\pi}{4})^8=5\left( \cos { 2\pi +i\sin { 2\pi  }  }  \right) =5$$

Comment: needed to use $(rcis\theta)^n=r^ncisn\theta$, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I dont' like the ''cis'' notation. If you write:
$$
z=\sqrt[8]{5}e^{\frac{2k \pi  i}{8}}\qquad, \qquad k=0,1,...,4
$$
you see that for $k=1$ we get:

$$
z^8=\left[\sqrt[8]{5}e^{\frac{2\pi i }{8}}\right]^8=5e^{2\pi i}=5
$$